# can we use spring+hibernate+google app engine and its no-sql datastore

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am planning to work on a application for which I want to integrate

- spring
- hibernate
- google app engine
- google no-sql datastore

Is it possible?

can someone please share any working code sample?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: hibernate is a SQL ORM, useless on App Engine. Try Objectify instead.

Comment: but hibernate 4.0 is OGM, so is there any way to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Hibernate OGM does not currently support Google Cloud Datastore. Currently there is support for:

- Infinispan
- Ehcache
- Redis (tech preview)
- MongoDB
- CouchDB (tech preview)
- Neo4j
- Cassandra (tech preview)

However, you can use JPA as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2). Anyway keep in mind the below warning.

> Warning: We think most developers will have a better experience using
>   the low-level Datastore API, or one of the open-source APIs developed
>   specifically for Datastore, such as Objectify. JPA was designed for
>   use with traditional relational databases, and so has no way to
>   explicitly represent some of the aspects of Datastore that make it
>   different from relational databases, such as entity groups and
>   ancestor queries. This can lead to subtle issues that are difficult to
>   understand and fix.